# On the complex projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, symplectic-geometry

We define the complex projective space $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$ as the set of complex lines in $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ through the origin.

- First, what is a complex line in $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}.?$
- How can we define coordinates in $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$?
- Wath is a line (respectively a point) in the projective space $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$?

Comment: (1) A complex 1D subspace, (2) homogeneous coordinates, (3) a 3D (resp 1D) complex subspace of $\Bbb C^{n+1}$

Comment: Thank you for that. this seams more clear to me. How can we define homogeneous coordinates in CPn.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can imagine that such definitions seem difficult at first.

Think about how you would define a line in $\mathbb{R}^2$, that would be $l:\vec{x}=\vec{a}+\lambda\cdot \vec{r}$, for $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ a direction vector $\vec{r}\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and a starting point $\vec{a}\in\mathbb{R}^2$, notice that this line $l$ goes through the point $a$.

An example would be
$$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\lambda\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix}\;\mbox{for}\;\lambda\in\mathbb{R}.$$
Then above is a line through the origin with direction $\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix}.$

Analogously, a line in $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ is of the form
$$l:\vec{x}=\vec{a}+\lambda \vec{b}\;\mbox{for}\;\lambda\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\;\mbox{and}\;\vec{a},\vec{b}\in\mathbb{C}^{n+1}.$$

Such a line goes through the origin if and only if $\vec{a}=\vec{0}$, the zero-vector, often denoted $0$.

Thus lines through the origin are of the form
$$l:\vec{x}=\lambda \vec{a}\;\mbox{for}\;\lambda\in\mathbb{C}\;\mbox{and}\;\vec{a}\in\mathbb{C}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}.$$

By above can we precisely say that two points $a$ and $b$ (not the origin) lie on the same line through the origin if and only if there exist a $\mu\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ such that $a=\mu b$.

This is used to define coordinates in $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$. Namely take a point $a\in\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$, which means $a=(a_0,...,a_n)$ with $a_i\in\mathbb{C}$ and not all $a_i$ equal to $0$. Then this gives a point in $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$ with coordinates $(a_0:...:a_n)$, which in fact is an equivalence class of points in $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ identified by the fact that $(a_0:...:a_n)=(b_0:...:b_n)$ if and only if there exist a $\mu\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ such that $(a_0,...,a_n)=\mu (b_0,...,b_n)\in\mathbb{C}^{n+1}.$

Note that above coincides with saying that $a$ and $b$ belong to the same line through the origin in $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$. We call elements $(a_0:...:a_n)$ points in $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$ (which in fact can be seen as lines in $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$.

Comment: Everywhere you say "$\lambda \in \Bbb C \setminus \{0\}$", where it should be just "$\lambda \in \Bbb C"$. Moreover, two vectors $u$ and $v$ lie in the same line if and only there exists $\lambda \in \Bbb C$ such that $u = \lambda v$ **or** $v = \lambda u$ (which then includes the cases $u=0$ or $v=0$)

Comment: I did write it on purpose to get rid of the origin, which is never an element of the projective space. And $u=\lambda v$ is equivalent to $v=\frac{1}{\lambda}u$ which works since $\lambda\neq 0$. See for example http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf chapter 4

Comment: No vector is an element of the projective space. Lines are, and lines do contain the origin. The description as a quotient indeed get rid of the origin, but that is just a matter of representation

Comment: Sorry I understand what you mean. You exclude the zero vector as direction, but not as scalar.

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful to me .